# Trying to find title of book from 70s or 80s about super intelligent being

Tags: story-identification

From memory, the story had some military themes. Person or being became increasingly powerful and telepathically connected to everything and everyone. Think it was primarily set in UK. There may have also been reference to people losing minds/senses. Would like to read again (as have clearly forgotten quite a bit about it!)

Comment: Other than the U.K. setting, it sounds like Blood Music by Greg Bear (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_Music_(novel)). Leaving this as a comment because it's a long shot.

Comment: Thanks. It's not the one I remember but might give it a go anyway.

Comment: Do you remember any of the following details: An investigator researching a report of a girl with psychic powers living on a remote Scottish island? The investigator later discovering that he has psychic powers himself? The use of sensory deprivation chambers? A Russian team of researchers who have kept a nine year old boy in a sensory deprivation chamber for all of his life?

Answer (score 1):

*[Fountains of Paradise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fountains_of_Paradise)* by Arthur C Clarke maybe?

> In the 22nd century, Dr Vannevar Morgan is a famous structural engineer who hopes to develop the 'space elevator' from a theoretical concept to reality and enlists the resources of his employers to carry out experiments. But the only suitable starting point (Earth station) for the elevator lies at the summit of a mountain in Taprobane occupied by an ancient order of Buddhist monks, who implacably oppose the plan.
>
> Morgan is approached by a Mars-based consortium to develop the elevator on Mars as part of a massive terraforming project. To demonstrate the viability of the technology, Morgan tries to run a thin cable of ‘hyperfilament’ from an orbital factory down to ground level at Taprobane. A monk at the monastery, a former astrophysicist who is a mathematical genius, tries to sabotage the attempt by creating an artificial hurricane using a hijacked weather-control satellite. His attempt succeeds, but the hurricane blows butterflies to the peak of the mountain. This fulfills an ancient prophecy that causes the monks to leave the mountain. The tower can be built on Earth after all.
>
> Forced to resign his position for acting beyond his authority, Morgan joins the Martian consortium named 'Astroengineering' and construction of the Tower commences.

Comment: One liner opinions can be posted as comment.

Comment: Why do you think so? Can you tell us what elements of the story caused you to suggest this, can you tells us how the story elements may differ. The more detail you provide the more helpful your answer will be.

Comment: I don't think this is the answer.  From what I recall, Fountains of Paradise was about a space elevator.  There are some advanced aliens, but they only have a probe at the beginning of the book as a plot device, and appear at the end when humanity has connected space elevators into a ring.  They are not part of the plot.